# What was the point of the Dameron's Force Tree?

Tags: star-wars, marvel

Perhaps I missed something.  As I was swept up in Star Wars fever, and I love comics, I purchased all 4 of the Shattered Empire books put out by Marvel in September and October.  In the 4th and final issue, there is the inclusion of Luke obtaining the last two trees from the Jedi Temple.  He kept one and gave the second tree to Shara Bey and Kes Dameron, Poe's parents.

What is the reason for this?  I would think that a force sensitive tree is a pretty important gift.  Certainly we don't know of Poe's force sensitivity; his flying is fantastic, and certainly being the best resistance pilot invokes feelings of Anakin being the best pilot.  But what are the trees for, what are they doing in the story, and should we expect that there will be story lines that include these trees in the future?  Or was it just supposed to be a feelgood "one shot" type of story?  It just seemed weird and out of place to me, and my friends and I are hoping, but reluctant to believe, that these trees will play ANY role in any screen or even comic events...

Comment: The last 2 mystical trees from the Temple... was someone at Disney reading too much Tolkien? :)

Comment: Don't think I have enough for a peoper answer, but (1) He gave one to Shara Bey because she was the one who helped Luke retrieve them from Imperial Base; (2) According to a twit from Greg Rucka - the author - the tree was Just Another McGuffin. Something Jedyish-artefactish for Luke to seek, but that wasn't an old boring Holocron

Comment: "Dameron"... "Force"... how is this question _not_ about Star Wars?!? lol... oh wait... it _is_ about Star Wars? I'm so confused. The marvel comics tag threw me off :(

Comment: @RedCaio made an edit and changed the second tag to simply comics, but it has to be reviewed first to take effect.

Comment: Why change it?  It is a star wars question?

Comment: @Thomas I switched it back. They are indeed marvel comics. It did confuse me, but marvel is correct.

Comment: @RedCaio ok, then the one who approved it, also overlooked this fact. Though I am still surprised that Marcel put out StarWars Comics.

Comment: @Thomas Disney owns Star Wars and Marvel

Comment: @Thomas ... and Marvel did that a long time ago, in ...actually this galaxy: http://marvel.com/comics/series/20108/star_wars_1977_-_1986

Comment: @DVK there's a Force sensitive tree in the Jedi Temple on Coruscant. It's either the oldest, or the only one. Possibly from the birth of the Temple or even the order. Palpatine had it removed when he moved in. Luke pursued it as a matter of principle: He considered it stolen from the Order by the Empire. The tree withered by the time Luke arrived, but there remained two living twigs, enough to be nurtured into new trees, but Luke only needed one, so he gave the other away in gratitude as spare parts.

Comment: @thegreatjedi - I wouldn't say it's "spare parts", more like "he trusted them to take as good care of it as himself". But as far as I can tell from WoG, either way it's a McGuffin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Greg Rucka](https://twitter.com/ruckawriter/status/656969225781665793), the force-trees are simply a [MacGuffin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin) of his own invention, something for Luke to *quest for* that isn't something we've seen before (multiple times)

> **[@cracksh0t](https://twitter.com/cracksh0t) 
>   Glad you liked it! [I] Wanted Luke to pursue something besides 'just another holocron'**
>
> — Greg Rucka (@ruckawriter) [October 21, 2015](https://twitter.com/ruckawriter/status/656969225781665793)

That being the case, it seems unlikely that we'll see them again. There's no special indication that Poe is a Jedi, nor that the trees have had any effect on him or his upbringing, nor do we see any evidence of the trees in the new Star Wars film.